set background color for day in package table_calendar flutter
I'm currently using table_calendar, I create a list to store my event then use event loader to show that. But I want, if that day has event it will have a random background color for that cell of day, or maybe can be selectted like this image not like the demo one with black dot ? How can I do that


you can customize each cell.
here the example:
 Widget _buildCellDate(DateTime day, {DateTime? focusedDay}) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: (day == focusedDay) ? BoxShape.circle : BoxShape.rectangle,
        color: bgclr, // you custom color here
        borderRadius: (day == focusedDay) ? null : BorderRadius.circular(4),
      ),
      child: Text(
        day.day.toString(),
        style: TextStyle(color: _getTxtColor(bgclr)),
      ),
    );
  }

Now use the _buildCellDate to your Table Calendar:
TableCalendar<MyModel>(
  // another setup here
  startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
  calendarBuilders: CalendarBuilders(
    selectedBuilder: (context, day, focusedDay) =>
        _buildCellDate(day, focusedDay: focusedDay),
    defaultBuilder: (context, day, focusedDay) => _buildCellDate(day),
    todayBuilder: (context, day, focusedDay) => _buildCellDate(day),
  ),
}

customize your cell on calendarBuilders. You can customize the selected, today and default cell.
and here the example result: I createa calendar HeatMap widget.


thank for this example. I will try it and tell about it later
